# Javascript download BLOB as PDF

Tags: javascript, pdf, blob

I am trying to convert a blob object to a pdf and download it.

So far I've tried the following:

```
var downloadLink = document.createElement('a');
            downloadLink.target = '_blank';
            downloadLink.download = 'name_to_give_saved_file.pdf';

            // convert downloaded data to a Blob
            var blob = new Blob([file.$binary], { type: 'application/pdf' });

            // create an object URL from the Blob
            var URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
            var downloadUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

            // set object URL as the anchor's href
            downloadLink.href = downloadUrl;

            // append the anchor to document body
            document.body.append(downloadLink);

            // fire a click event on the anchor
            downloadLink.click();
```

The file size seems to be correct, but I cant view it since it seems to be damaged.

Viewing the PDF inside of my html file works like this:

```
 $('#test').html('<embed width=100% height=100%'
            + ' type="application/pdf"'
            + ' src="data:application/pdf;base64,'
            + escape(file.$binary)
            + '"></embed>')
```

This works without any problems!

Now to my question... why is one working and the other one isn't?

Thanks for your help...

Comment: Is your `file.$binary` the binary PDF data or is it base64 data?

Comment: I believe it is the binary PDF data!
The file object looks like this:
`
$binary: "JVBERi0xLjQKJcK1wrYKCjEgMCBvYmoKPDwvQXJ0Qm94WzAgM...."
$type: "00"
`

Comment: Yep, it's not the binary file.  It's a string, containing the base64 representation of the binary data.  Note how your `<embed>` tag has `data:application/pdf;base64,`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `file.$binary` is not binary data (even though the object name is `$binary).  It's actually a *string* containing the base64 representation of binary data.

So, before making a `Blob`, you need to convert the string to the binary data.

You can do so using the following (from https://stackoverflow.com/a/16245768):

```
const b64toBlob = (b64Data, contentType='', sliceSize=512) => {
  const byteCharacters = atob(b64Data);
  const byteArrays = [];

  for (let offset = 0; offset < byteCharacters.length; offset += sliceSize) {
    const slice = byteCharacters.slice(offset, offset + sliceSize);

    const byteNumbers = new Array(slice.length);
    for (let i = 0; i < slice.length; i++) {
      byteNumbers[i] = slice.charCodeAt(i);
    }

    const byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
    byteArrays.push(byteArray);
  }

  const blob = new Blob(byteArrays, {type: contentType});
  return blob;
}
```

Then you can do

```
var blob = b64toBlob(file.$binary, 'application/pdf');
```

---

Looking at other answers on the same question (https://stackoverflow.com/a/36183085), there is a smaller way to do this:

```
const b64toBlob = (base64, type = 'application/octet-stream') => 
    fetch(`data:${type};base64,${base64}`).then(res => res.blob())
```

Then you can still do

```
var blob = b64toBlob(file.$binary, 'application/pdf');
```